# How to set a value of a variable during a test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automation

Suppose I have a code in Java (or any other language) that I want to test. Let's say that I want to test how the code behaves when variable 'myVar' holds an integer value of 10 at a certain line.

One option will be to assign the value 10 to variable 'myVar' at this line. This will work fine, but it will make the code dirty. If I want to test another scenario, I'll have to fix this line. What will happen if I have a huge number of scenarios ?

I was wondering whether there is an option to hold an external file/configuration that will be loaded whenever I want to test this specific scenario without modifying the code?

Comment: Key search phrase: **dependency injection**.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use a Json File. Just put your value into the Json file "test.json" at location c:\testfolder with following content:

```
{
    "Scenario":"10"
}
```

Now you can access the value using following code in C#:

```
StreamReader file = File.OpenText("c:\testfolder\test.json");
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file);
JObject jObject = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
int a = jObject ["Scenario"];
```

You can use this variable a which contains value 10 from the Json file.